# Unable to create a service builder into a Liferay portlet app

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, liferay-6

I do not manage to create a proper service.xml into my portlet application to use service builder.

1) Firstly, if I try to use Eclipse IDE:
- right click on project
- liferay service builder
Plugin project select box is empty and I cannot click finish. I get an "Enter a project name" notification.

2) If I try to manually create a service.xml file into WEB-INF/ or WEB-INF/src with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE service-builder PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Service Builder 6.2.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-service-builder_6_0_0.dtd">

<service-builder package-path="com.aveo.openemm.servicebuilder">, 
</service-builder>
```

the file is just a regular xml file and does not act as a service builder file.
Opening it in Eclipse does not offer an"overview" mode, which would allow me to create and manage my entities as expected.

The project was built with Maven (in case it makes a difference).

I ve no clue how to move forward at this stage.
Thx for your kind assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Liferay 6.2.1 and Liferay maven plugin 6.2.10.9

If you are just starting out and using maven then I would suggest starting a new project using

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=liferay-servicebuilder-archetype -DarchetypeGroupId=com.liferay.maven.archetypes -DarchetypeVersion=6.2.10.13 -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=Test -Dversion=1.00.000 -DpackageName=com.example -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Replacing com.example and "Test"  with your information.

Your service.xml should be located in your Test/Test-portlet/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF folder.  It will look something like

```
<!DOCTYPE service-builder PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Service Builder 6.1.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-service-builder_6_1_0.dtd">

<service-builder package-path="com.example.dao">
    <namespace>example</namespace>

    <entity name="Reservation" uuid="true" local-service="true" remote-service="false">

            <!-- PK fields -->

            <column name="reservationId" type="long" primary="true" id-type="increment" />

            <!-- Audit fields -->

            <column name="userId" type="long" />
            <column name="companyId" type="long" />
            <column name="groupId" type="long" />

            <!-- Other fields -->

            <column name="fileEntryId" type="long" />
            <column name="serialId" type="long" />
            <column name="reserveDate" type="Date" />
            <column name="checkoutDate" type="Date" />
            <column name="checkinDate" type="Date" />
            <column name="indefinite" type="String"/>


            <!-- Order -->

            <order by="asc">
                <order-column name="reservationId" />
            </order>

            <!-- Finder methods -->

            <finder name="ReservationId" return-type="Reservation">
                <finder-column name="reservationId" />
            </finder>

            <finder name="UserId" return-type="Collection">
                <finder-column name="userId" />
            </finder>

            <finder name="FileEntryId" return-type="Collection">
                <finder-column name="fileEntryId" />
            </finder>

            <finder name="UserFile" return-type="Collection">
                <finder-column name="userId" />
                <finder-column name="fileEntryId" />
            </finder>

            <finder name="FileSerial" return-type="Collection">
                <finder-column name="fileEntryId" />
                <finder-column name="serialId" />
            </finder>
    </entity>

</service-builder>
```

You will also want to edit your Test/pom.xml and add the following

```
<properties>
  <liferay.maven.plugin.version>6.2.10.13</liferay.maven.plugin.version>
  <liferay.version>6.2.1</liferay.version>
</properties>
```

It should go right before the closing project tag.

Then using the command line in your Test/ directory you would run

```
mvn liferay:build-service
```

You can find out more from the following:  http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/service-builder-liferay-portal-6-1-dev-guide-en .

Comment: Personally I use Netbeans with my Maven projects.

Comment: The liferay link did not help.
But the mvn liferay:build-service command made my pre-generated file work.
Thank you very much for letting me know about it :)